# Order mysql data from another table IDs

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to order by greater `SUM(amount)` IDs from table `webhooks`, to fetch messages.

Webhooks Table

```
CREATE TABLE `webhooks` (
  `id` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  `from_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

webhooks DATA:

```
INSERT INTO `webhooks` (`to_id`, `from_id`, `amount`, `created_at`) VALUES
('1273817', '15992', 9.99, '1605642691'),
('1273817', '11813', 8, '1605642189'),
('38218', '47348', 5.99, '1605642142'),
('188277', '39123', 8, '1605641928'),
('188277', '47348', 10, '1605639932');
```

Messages table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `time` double NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Messages DATA:

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`from_id`, `to_id`, `message`, `time`) VALUES
(1273817, 43802, 'Hey there how are you', 1605643518.3869),
(46804, 1273817, 'Hello there!!', 1605643487.5376),
(45937, 1273817, 'Wowww', 1605642552.2655),
(47348, 38218, 'yayyy!!!', 1605642523.0497),
(47348, 43802, 'Are you there?', 1605640241.813);
```

Here is my messages query, but i have to order by greatest webhooks amount `to_id` `SUM(amount)`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   c.from_id,
   c.to_id 
FROM
   messages c 
   JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            CASE
               WHEN
                  `from_id` = '$uid' 
               THEN
                  `to_id` 
               ELSE
                  `from_id` 
            END
            AS other, MAX(time) AS latest 
         FROM
            messages 
         WHERE
            (
               `from_id` = '$uid' 
               OR `to_id` = '$uid'
            )
            AND to_id != '0' 
         GROUP BY
            other
      )
      m 
      ON (c.from_id = '$uid' 
      AND c.to_id = m.other 
      OR c.to_id = '$uid' 
      AND c.from_id = m.other) 
      AND c.time = m.latest 
ORDER BY
   time DESC LIMIT $ offset, $ limit
```

The desired results should be the same as the query, but not to `ORDER BY time DESC` but to `ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC` from `webhooks` table.

Comment: Tip: Don't do literal `'$uid'` but instead `?` and then bind values to those.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Join with the `webhooks` table and then use the desired columns in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Strawberry updated, can you check it now. Thank you

Comment: @Barmar i don't know how to order by SUM(amount) then i got multiple same rows i've tried it, but i don't know what im missing.

Comment: Show what the desired result should be.

Comment: Why are `from/to_id` integers in one table and varchar in the other?

Comment: @Barmar the desired results should be the same as the query, but not to `ORDER BY time DESC` but to `ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC` from `webhooks` table. I don't know why i've did that one integer and another varchar.

Comment: @Barmar im trying to get the first messages of users that have spent the most to order by.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64882166/edit) to show the results that you want for this sample data.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an int declaration is almost meaningless- which is just as well, because a 200 digit integer would be a figure larger than the number of atoms in the observable universe.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: @smokzz That's why they posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN with the `webhooks` table and use `GROUP BY from_id, to_id`, then you can order by `SUM(amount) DESC`.

```
SELECT
   c.from_id,
   c.to_id 
FROM
   messages c 
   JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            CASE
               WHEN
                  `from_id` = '$uid' 
               THEN
                  `to_id` 
               ELSE
                  `from_id` 
            END
            AS other, MAX(time) AS latest 
         FROM
            messages 
         WHERE
            (
               `from_id` = '$uid' 
               OR `to_id` = '$uid'
            )
            AND to_id != '0' 
         GROUP BY
            other
      )
      m 
      ON (c.from_id = '$uid' 
        AND c.to_id = m.other 
        OR c.to_id = '$uid' 
        AND c.from_id = m.other) 
        AND c.time = m.latest 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 0 + from_id AS from_id_int, 0 + to_id AS to_id_int, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM webhooks
    GROUP BY from_id, to_id
) AS w ON w.from_id_int = c.from_id AND w.to_id_int = c.to_id
ORDER BY w.amount DESC
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224814/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-order-mysql-data-from-another-table-ids).